# Does exists difference in order of comparison?

Tags: java, string, compare

What is better use for:

```
String s=.....
...............//some calculation

final String const="abcd";

 s.compareTo(const)
```

or

```
const.compareTo(s)
```

?

Thanks.

Comment: `const` is a keyword. you cannot use it for variable names

Answer (score 4):

I very much doubt that it matters in terms of performance. <strike>If there's any chance that `s` is `null`, then prefer `const.compareTo(s)`.</strike> (Actually, if `s` is `null`, you're going to get a `NullPointerException` with `compareTo()` one way or the other.)

Answer (score 2):

The result would be sign inversed for the two comparisons. In other words, if `s.compareTo(const) == 1` then `const.compareTo(s) == -1`.

Other than that it is the same. It is generally a good idea to use `const.compareTo(s)` instead of the alternative since this avoids a potential null exception.

Answer (score 1):

many prefer to use `const.compareTo(s)`
 because it will work in case `s` null is, but I find it less readable.